# date can not be serialized

Tags: pandas, parquet, fastparquet

I am getting an error while trying to save the dataframe as a file.

```
from fastparquet import write 
write('profile_dtl.parq', df)
```

The error is related to "date" and the error message looks like this...

```
ValueError: Can't infer object conversion type: 0    1990-01-01
1    1954-01-01
2    1981-11-15
3    1993-01-21
4    1948-01-01
5    1977-01-01
6    1968-04-28
7    1969-01-01
8    1989-01-01
9    1985-01-01
Name: dob, dtype: object
```

I have checked that the column is "object" just like any other column that can be serialized without any problem. If I remove the "dob" column from the dataframe, then this line will work. This will also work if there is date+time.

Only dates are not accepted by fast-parquet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `dob` to `datetime64` dtype:

```
import pandas as pd
dob = pd.Series(['1954-01-01', '1981-11-15', '1993-01-21', '1948-01-01',
                 '1977-01-01', '1968-04-28', '1969-01-01', '1989-01-01',
                 '1985-01-01'], name='dob')
Out:
0    1954-01-01
1    1981-11-15
2    1993-01-21
3    1948-01-01
4    1977-01-01
5    1968-04-28
6    1969-01-01
7    1989-01-01
8    1985-01-01
Name: dob, dtype: object
```

Note the dtype that results:

```
pd.to_datetime(dob)

Out:
0   1954-01-01
1   1981-11-15
2   1993-01-21
3   1948-01-01
4   1977-01-01
5   1968-04-28
6   1969-01-01
7   1989-01-01
8   1985-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Using this Series as an index in a DataFrame:

```
baz = list(range(9))
foo = pd.DataFrame(baz, index=pd.to_datetime(dob), columns=['dob'])
```

You should be able to save your Parquet file now.

```
from fastparquet import write

write('foo.parquet', foo)
```

```
$ls -l foo.parquet
-rw-r--r--  1 moi  admin  854 Oct 13 16:44 foo.parquet
```

---

Your `dob` Series has an object dtype and you left unchanged the `object_encoding='infer'` argument to `fastparquet.write`. So, from the [docs](http://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write):

> "The special value 'infer' will cause the type to be guessed from the first ten non-null values."

Fastparquet does not [try to infer](http://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/fastparquet/writer.html?highlight=find_type) a date value from what it expects to be one of `bytes|utf8|json|bson|bool|int|float`.